# having the properties list of active directory's user

Tags: c#, winforms, active-directory, .net-3.5

In my project I need to change the properties of any user from the active directory (AD). 
I found the way to change a property of a user, but I should already know it.

1. Is there a function that can list all the properties of "AD" and if
   that is not possible can you give me a site that lists all the
   properties?
2. Is it possible to change any user's property?
3. Are there other constraints that I have not considered?

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: Check out [the Hilltop Lab web site](http://www.rlmueller.net/Links_and_References.htm) - Richard has a whole slew of reference lists, e.g. [all Active Directory attributes](http://www.rlmueller.net/UserAttributes.htm) and more.

Comment: I imagine that the properties are not all accessible and others are read only.
Is there a function which list the accessible properties or writable properties?
Thank your in advance :)

Comment: Have you looked at the spreadsheet of **ALL** AD attributes? Can't be more thorough than that.... those properties **are** accessible - if you have the appropriate permissions - and those properties are all also writeable - if you have the necessary permissions,.